# Apache2.4 ProxyPass exception inside Location block not working

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, redirect

While trying to get the Let's Encrypt Certbot to work on a local server that hosts reverse-proxied content, I am unable to get the local exception working inside a `Location` block. `httpd.conf` snippet:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass "https://internal.host/"
    ProxyPassReverse "https://internal.host/"
</Location>
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/01_acme.include
```

Placing the `01_acme.include` file above or below the `Location` block has no effect.

The `01_acme.include` file:

```
<Location /.well-known/acme-challenge/>
    ProxyPass "!"
    Alias /run/acme/.well-known/acme-challenge
</Location>
```

I have placed a single text file in that directory named `date`. Attempting to retrieve this file results in an endless 301 redirect to `date/index.html/index.html/...` until the redirect limit of the client is reached. The logs show this is generated on the front-end server, the back-end never receives a request.

If I replace the Location block with standalone directives, it functions as expected:

```
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge /run/acme/.well-known/acme-challenge
ProxyPass /.well-known/acme-challenge !
```

According to the [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) documentation this method of defining an exception should work - it conforms very well with the provided sample configuration towards the end of that section. Is this just broken, or have I missed something?

The redirects may be the root cause, but I can't find any redirect or rewrite directives in this scope that could be throwing a 301, and the only mention of index.html in `.htaccess` (there isn't one) or configuration files is the directory index, which I've tried explicitly disabling with `Options -Indexes` to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a trailing slash in the `Alias`. Trailing slashes have to match.

```
<Location /.well-known/acme-challenge/>
    ProxyPass "!"
    Alias /run/acme/.well-known/acme-challenge/
</Location>
```